# data exchange of two windows WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-exchange

I´m actually programming a WPF-application. Now, I´m just a beginner in WPF and so I´ve a problem:

In window A, there is a checkbox with some values. If I click on a button on window A, window B should open. On window B, I have a textfield and a save-button. When I click on the button on window B and close it, the value of the textfield should be in the checkbox on window A.

First, I programmed this with Windows Forms and there I solved it with BindingSource. This doesn´t work in WPF. 
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say that this nothign to do with `WPF` ot `WindowsForms`, as idea can be applied in both places. Just use a shared between different forms `DataStructure` that holds and information you need and changed from different forms. Just to give a simple idea:

```
public class DataStructure 
{
   //properties 
}

public Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1(DataStructure ds) {}
}



public Form2 : Form 
{
    public Form2(DataStructure ds) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PageFunction allows you to return a value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615540.aspx

Comment: It is a return value from a Navigation Page.  Now I am concerned with your use of lower case window.   If you want the Windows from two or more separate application to communicate then that is more complex.  If you have a master application and want to launch one of more children then Navigation is way to do that with two way communication.  See the link in my answer.